# Stepper Motor sometimes working fine and other times not

Tags: stm32, timer, stepper-motor, encoder

I am experimenting with operating a [Stepper Motor](https://www.faulhaber.com/fileadmin/Import/Media/EN_AM1020_FPS.pdf) that is connected to a [Magnetic Encoder](https://www.micromo.com/media/pdfs/HEAM1020.pdf). The Stepper Motor is also connected to a [Motor Driver](https://www.allegromicro.com/en/products/motor-drivers/brush-dc-motor-drivers/a4985), which will be controlled by an STM32F4 microcontroller.

This motor will be installed in a system where the motor will move an object, and this object can only move a certain and fixed amount of distance from its point of origin. When the object is at its furthest point from its point of origin, this object will not be able to move, and the motor should also not be able to rotate as it cannot push/drive this object further. (This object cannot go further as it will be physically blocked).

I recently learned that the Magnetic Encoder, coupled with the Quadrature Encoder Interface of the STM32F4 microcontroller (which is a TIM1 in Encoder Mode), will not retain the motor's position after a power cycle occurs. So, if a motor has moved a certain amount of distance from its origin, and the power to the microcontroller is lost, this position will not be retained. The next time the STM32F4 microcontroller gets power, it will read a position/distance of zero even though the motor has moved prior to the microcontroller turning off.

**Problem**:

I am trying to implement resetting the motor position at system startup, where the motor goes to the furthest point from the origin point (by turning the motor clockwise), and back to the origin point (by turning the motor counterclockwise). This way, I can also calculate the maximum number of steps/distance the motor can also drive the object. This process works most of the time, but fails several times too. Sometimes, the motor just rotates counterclockwise without going to the furthest point beforehand. Other times, the motor does not seem to go to either the origin point or the furthest point visually. On rare occasions, the motor goes to the furthest point, but gets stuck.

I used a Logic Analyzer and Oscilloscope to observe the two channels that represent the Motor's position (Quadrature Encoder Interface). I noticed that sometimes, when it does not go to its furthest point and back to its origin point (or when it fails to perform the motor reset), the two channels might have some noise/jitter when the motor first moves.

The image/screenshot below is the signals when the motor properly resets its position at startup:

[image: Motor successfully resetting its position]

Other times, these are the signals I am getting when the motor does not go to its furthest distance first before going to its origin point (motor turning counterclockwise immediately):

[image: Motor turning counterclockwise without going clockwise first]

These are the signals that I also get if the motor does not seem to do anything visually at system startup:

[image: No reset]

[image: No reset 2]

[image: No reset in Oscilloscope]

[image: No reset in Oscilloscope 2]

In the 4 pictures above, visually, the motor did not do anything. However, it seems that at startup, the motor does go clockwise first and rising edges were actually triggered, but it immediately went counterclockwise before doing nothing. In the last two oscilloscope pictures, there are some signals sometime after the purple lines go low (which represents DIR). These signals represent the motor being moved periodically by a Timer interrupt, which happens after the motor position reset.

**Question**: What could be the issue here? Is it normal for the encoders to be noisy/jittery right after the system starts? Why does it appear randomly (not all the time, or none at all)?

The code is fairly straightforward. I set the DIR, STEP pins to its respective levels before initiating this reset. I turn DIR into clockwise, and issue rising edge outputs on the STEP pin. This happens in a while loop where I check `TIM1->CNT` that represents the position of the motor before I increase the motor's step, and afterwards. The while loop compares the old position with the new position. This is the pseudocode:

```
/* Rotate motor clockwise position to reach furthest point */
MotorDirection(CLOCKWISE);
Delay_ms(1);

do
{
   OldPosition = TIM1->CNT;
   MotorIncreaseStep();
   Delay_ms(1);
   NewPosition = TIM1->CNT;
} while (OldPosition != NewPosition);
```

The pseudocode above also applies to the counterclockwise direction, where the motor pulls the object to its origin point.

**What I tried**: I tried increasing delays between reads to 3 or 5 ms because I thought that it takes some time for the `TIM1->CNT` registers to update. I also thought that a longer delay would also give time for the encoder/motor to settle. This approach did not seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Update**: I used the Oscilloscope to do more traces/scoping of the STEP/DIR/ChannelA/ChannelB lines when DIR goes high (instructs motor to turn counterclockwise) as suggested by a user here. In the pictures below, Yellow line represents STEP, blue represents DIR, purple represents Channel A, and green represents Channel B.

The pictures below are the scope results of when the motor immediately turns counterclockwise after reset visually. In reality, it did turn clockwise for a few steps before reversing:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have also attached scope/traces of the same lines where the motor rotates clockwise normally until it reaches the furthest position, but fails to reverse to its origin point:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

From some of the pictures above, it might seem as if the Channel A and Channel B's outputs change longer than usual (or sometimes do not change at all)?

Comment: Those tiny glitches don't look bothersome to me.    Your "good" trace shows DIR never changes, but the failed ones it changes almost immediately?  What is it about your test that causes DIR to change that is failing?   That is the question you need to ask yourself.   I would be looking at timing --- What state are the inputs in when the test executes?  You might need to zoom way in on your scope to see the exact timing relations.  You can trigger on DIR - When it changes state, stop the scan and zoom in.

Comment: @KyleB The DIR seems to change immediately because the value of `TIM1->CNT` before the step increase and that value after the step increase seems to not change, so the software seems to think that the motor has reached the furthest position even though it hasn't

Comment: @KyleB Could you explain what you meant when you asked about the state of the inputs when the test executes? I basically scope/trace through Logic Analyzer before turning on the system, and I keep the scope/trace results of the tests that fail (visually). Is it also possible that I am reading the `TIM1->CNT` registers too fast? This register increases (if motor is moving clockwise and single step) or decreases by 2 based on the two channels

Comment: I meant that your scope traces are too small to see the resolution of EXACTLY what state your inputs are in at EXACTLY the time the CPU attempts to read them.  1 microsecond is an eternity to a CPU.   You want to be able to precisely see those inputs at the exact moment your test trigger DIR to change, so you can tell if you have a hardware or a software issue.   That's your first step to troubleshooting.

Comment: Your scope traces are 100ms edge-to-edge.  Looking at the scope (not the logic analyzer), it's impossible to tell if DIR changes at the same time as the inputs or not.  A screen width of maybe 1ms is more reasonable.  Then you can visually see exactly what state the inputs are in.   DIR trips in the first scope pic when trace #1 changes state (maybe), but trips when #2 changes in the second pic.    Why is that????

Comment: @KyleB Thanks for the explanation! I made an update to the post to include the scope traces that you suggested doing. It might be that in most cases, the DIR immediately changes unexpectedly because `TIM1` might be reading the same outputs of Channel A and B, before and after the rising edge to STEP was issued

Comment: :)  Much better   ---   I'm not familiar with the ST series of micros, especially its timer functions, but the thing that jumps out at me is in the last picture, trace #4 has a pulse that is clearly less than 1ms in length.  Yet your loop has a 1ms delay.  Does that imply it is possible for your code to completely miss that pulse???

Comment: @KyleB It might be possible that I do miss that pulse. I am actually trying to slow the motor down and see if it helps with my timing issues. I just realized that the timing parameters should be based on the motor itself, and not the motor driver. Hopefully this way, the encoder signals will also be cleaner and slower.